# Not able to perform performance testing on WhatsApp, Facebook App

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

I want to perform performance testing on Play store apps like WhatsApp, Facebook, Etc, I am able to perform the same on my company App but not other app.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I am using Jmeter,, when i am trying to record it, its not recording

Answer (score 1):

Most probably these applications use [SSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SSL_Glossary) for communication with the backend server(s) so you need to perform a some form of [MITM attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) in order to be able to capture and decrypt outgoing requests and incoming responses.

The solution is installing JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device

1. Run JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Locate JMeter's certificate in its "bin" folder: **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt**
3. Transfer it to device somehow (i.e. send it to yourself by email)
4. Click on the attachment and follow your OS dialog in order to install the certificate
5. Configure your device to use JMeter as a proxy

---

Troubleshooting tips (if it still doesn't work)

- Make sure cellular network is disabled on the mobile device and it is connected using Wi-Fi only
- Make sure JMeter and mobile device are on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and you can reach JMeter host from the device and vice versa (verify it using commands line [ping](https://www.lifewire.com/ping-command-2618099) and [telnet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx))
- In some cases you will need a 3rd-party app like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) in order to enable proxying of secure traffic
- You can also try out using cloud-based recording service, it automates proxy creation and certificate installation steps. As a bonus you can export recorded script in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic correlation of dynamic parameters, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, But I have already installed ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt certificate in Mobile phone but still its not recording for some apps.